# C++ Avoid passing variable to std::cout if its value is zero

Tags: c++, cout

Suppose I have a variable, `double x`, as a result of some calculations, which can have any value, including zero, and I need it passed to `std::cout`. How can I avoid printing `x` if its value is zero?

As an example, this will print `1+<value_of_x>` if `x`, else just `1`:

`std::cout << (x ? "1+" : "1") << x << '\n';`

Is there a way to make the same but for `x`? Something like the following nonsense:

`std::cout << (x ? ("1+" << x) : "1") << '\n';`

I should probably add that I am not advanced in C++.

Comment: Why don't you just put a check (using an `if`) before your call to `std::cout` instead of trying to do some fancy inline check?

Comment: What about `if (!x) std::cout << "1\n" else std::cout << "1+"<< x << "\n"` ?

Comment: You're both right, I didn't consider it. I suppose this is something that comes with practise...

Comment: @UnholySheep For me a check is a check, nothing "fancy" about it, but if you say it is, then I'll try to use them less in the future.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen What Sheep was pointing out is that the ternary operator usually makes code less readable and usually a normal if else will do the job just fine.

Comment: @GillBates If conditions demand it, is there a way to mark the inline check to be visible and not make the code less readable? Sometimes, this sort of check saves several lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say

```
std::cout << (x ? "1+" + std::to_string(x) : "1") << '\n';
```

but

```
if (x)
    std::cout << "1+" << x << '\n';
else
    std::cout << "1" << '\n';
```

is perhaps more readable.
(I consider this largely a matter of personal preference.)

Comment: This is better, regarding the comment on @PeteBecker, thank you! If nothing better comes, I'll choose this as the answer.

Comment: I am trying to print out a polynomial, where the coefficients are calculated and I have to print it ...humanly. This means there can be a lot of `if` statements in there, which, in my opinion, they would be less readable than carefully aligning and stacking the inline checks. Maybe it's just me, but most probably it's my lack of experience.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Why would there be a lot of conditionals? You should only need one, inside a loop or a function.

Comment: Only saw this today. Not all the terms of the polynomial are `!=0`, it can happen that the result is `x^20+1`, which would print `x^20+0*x^19+0*x^18+...+0*x+1`, which looks not only ugly, but deceiving and stressing on the eyes, too. To make things more difficult, this polynomial will, later on, be divided, so separate, lower oder polynomials will be printed. I'm afraid I don't see too many options.

Answer (score 1):

If `x` is 0, don't print it:

```
if (x != 0)
    std::cout << x << '\n';
```

Any further variations should be self-evident.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I wonder if the down-voters forgot what it's like to be a beginner? This simply did not occur to me. There might be a problem with longer lines, though, chained, like `cout << (check1) << (check2) << stuff << other_stuff << ...`, because I'd rather not add kilometric lines in duplicate.

Comment: The '+' is missing ?

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen if I understand your problem correctly, you might consider building the string based on the conditions (e.g.: you declare a `std::string` variable, then do your checks and modify the string according and after you did all your checks pass your string to `std::cout`

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen - longer lines can be split into shorter ones. For a case like the one in the question, first write out the stuff that comes before `x`, then decide whether to write `x`, then write out the stuff that comes after.

Comment: @UnholySheep - that approach just leads to the followup question: "C++ Avoid passing variable to `std::string` if variable is zero".

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen - re: "this simply did not occur to me: -- that's a common problem: getting deep into coding something and lose perspective, overlooking a far simpler solution. Sometimes the best approach is to take a walk.

Comment: @UnholySheep I see what you mean. That would involve a loop for setting up the iteration variables, added with `push_back`, or one of those (IIRC). #PeteBecker In the iteration, I could use `continue` for that case, I suppose, or a check inside the `for (... check ...)`? At any rate, so far molbdnilo's solution seems the most promising.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's something I do everytime things get fuzzy, step back to see the larger picture, but C++? I only started some month ago (or so), so I suppose I need some time to get used to.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen what iteration variable? I'm sorry but your problem description seems incomplete. You stated you have multiple different checks, there was no mention of any loops or iterations you have to do.

Comment: @UnholySheep I meant that I would need a loop to convert the coefficients (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39055809/c-avoid-passing-variable-to-stdcout-if-variable-is-zero#comment65460901_39055907) to strings, and, to avoid what PeteBecker said about the possible followup question, in that loop, I could have used additional checks. The "iteration variable" would have been `i` in `for (int i=0...)`.If it has a different, consacrated name, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Well this is going way beyond the original question so let's stop this discussion here.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `if` statement would be a simple and readable approach:

```
if (x)
    std::cout << "1+" << x;
else
    std::cout << "1";
std::cout << '\n';
```

Or even:

```
std::cout << "1";
if (x) std::cout << "+" << x;
std::cout << '\n';
```

But, if you really want to print out the value inline, you can define a custom `operator<<` to format the value however you want:

```
struct to_coefficient_str
{
    double m_value;

    to_coefficient_str(double value) : m_value(value) {}

    void print(std::ostream &out) const
    {
        out << "1";
        if (m_value)
            out << "+" << m_value;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const to_coefficient_str &ce)
{
    ce.print(out);
    return out;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
std::cout << to_coefficient_str(x) << '\n';
```

Comment: This is a nice alternative, thank you for the solution.